# Xamarin Tesseract OCR binding for Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, ocr, tesseract

I would like to use tesseract ocr for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS applications.
I found the binding for iOS (https://github.com/jherby2k/Xamarin-Tesseract-OCR-iOS-Unified).

Is there an equivalent for Android ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is Tesseract for Android implementation. You can find it [here](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two). But you'll have to build it and create android bindings by yourself.

EDIT

I created Xamarin Android binding based on this project. You can find it [here](https://github.com/halkar/tess-two-xamarin-android-binding). There is a test project, just don't forget that you will need Tesseract testdata to be copied on the device.

Comment: Take a look on the binding I generated.

Comment: Works great, that's what I needed.
Did you use a tool to generate the binding (.xml files) ?
Where does the classes.jar comes from ?
Thanks.

Comment: I've downloaded tess-two and built jar and so files by instruction.
BTW, if you still need it I've created new project to wrap Tesseract for iOS and Android together https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Tesseract/
It uses latest available version of Tesseract for iOS and Android.

Comment: Is there a way to implement it for realtime use via a TextureView without memory issues ?