# No System.Drawing dll

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, tesseract, system.drawing

This is probably a dumb question but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  I'm trying to use the a Tesseract C# wrapper (https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) and I've got it all working except for one error that reads

> Error 11  The type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

My first thought was "oh, let me just add an assembly reference to System.Drawing".  Except there isn't one.  When I right click References in the Solution Explorer -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Framework there is no System.Drawing.  I did find System.Drawing.dll under COM, but it won't let me add it, saying

> The ActiveX type Library [path] was exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference.  Add a reference to the .NET assembly instead.

Typing "using System.Drawing" at the top of my program does not cause an error, but it also does not solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Am I in the right place? [image: Where I'm looking for (and not finding) the library.]

Comment: I seem to remember a Xamarin blog post or something where they said they were considering implementing System.Drawing on all platforms, but I don't know if that's actually been done.  [This documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Drawing/) seems to indicate it hasn't:

Comment: It wants System.Drawing version 4.0.0.0. Are you targeting a different version of the .NET Framework?

Comment: @adv12 AAAAAAAHHHHHH that's idiotic.  It's a basic C# system reference, is there no way to get it functional?  I only need it for a third party library.  And Tergiver I had literally no idea, I don't think it lets me select because it's compiling with Xamarin.

Comment: For reference, here's the blog post: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2014/Aug-20.html

Comment: What platforms are you targeting?

Comment: You should be in the right place - but shouldn't there be a target Framework version be mentioned in that dialog? Maybe check your project properties for the right version?

Comment: It says "Targeting: Xamarin.Android v5.0 Support."  It does not let me specify which .NET version to target (at least not that I can find).

Comment: Ok, in that case @adv12 is right. The blog post he links describes that System.Drawing is just implemented in Xamarin for iOS so far, and not yet available for Android.

Comment: Damn, so no way to work around that?

Answer (score 0):

You won't go far with this project, there's this dependency for `System.Drawing` and the whole project doesn't seem like it's targeted towards Xamarin.

As written here [Xamarin Tesseract OCR binding for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533701/xamarin-tesseract-ocr-binding-for-android) there are bindings for  `Xamarin.iOS`, and the person is asking for bindings for `Xamarin.Android`. There's indeed a version of tesseract for Android here https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two and apparently the response is to create a binding to this Java Android version.

Both projects, the binding for `Xamarin.iOS` as well as `Xamarin.Android` are bindings to platform specific bindings who both wrap the native C++ library. Probably the best solution would be to completely bypass the `Java` and `Objective-C` wrapper by create a specific `P/Invoke` wrapper  for `C#`using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).